# foobar.withgoogle.com task Please Pass the Coded Messages java

Tags: java

I'm working on foobar.withgoogle task "Please Pass the Coded Messages", I got correct calculations on my computer for every possible number, but foobar prints "Test 5 failed [Hidden]" what means this Hidden test? could you please help me?

my result:

Verifying solution...

Test 1 passed!

Test 2 passed!

Test 3 passed! [Hidden]

Test 4 passed! [Hidden]

Test 5 failed  [Hidden]

## Please Pass the Coded Messages

You need to pass a message to the bunny workers, but to avoid detection, the code you agreed to use is... obscure, to say the least. The bunnies are given food on standard-issue plates that are stamped with the numbers 0-9 for easier sorting, and you need to combine sets of plates to create the numbers in the code. The signal that a number is part of the code is that it is divisible by 3. You can do smaller numbers like 15 and 45 easily, but bigger numbers like 144 and 414 are a little trickier. Write a program to help yourself quickly create large numbers for use in the code, given a limited number of plates to work with.

You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

## Languages

To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java
To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1})
Output:
4311

Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9})
Output:
94311

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1])
Output:
4311

Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9])
Output:
94311

Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed from your home folder.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Solution {
   public static int solution(int[] l) {
        List<Integer> initList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> resList = new ArrayList<>();

        Queue<Integer> rem0queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> rem1queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> rem2queue = new LinkedList<>();

        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        int result = 0, sum = 0, rem;

        for(int x: l){
            if(x < 0) return result;
            initList.add(x);
        }

        Collections.sort(initList);
        //System.out.println(initList);

        for(int y: initList) {
            sum += y;
            if((y % 3) == 0) rem0queue.add(y);
            else if((y % 3) == 1) rem1queue.add(y);
            else rem2queue.add(y);
        }

        if(sum == 0) return result;
        rem = sum % 3;



        switch (rem) {
            case 0:
                resList.addAll(rem0queue);
                resList.addAll(rem1queue);
                resList.addAll(rem2queue);
                resList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

                for(int x: resList) sbResult.append(x);
                result = Integer.parseInt(sbResult.toString());
                break;

            case 1:
                if(!rem1queue.isEmpty()) rem1queue.remove();
                else {
                    if(!rem2queue.isEmpty()) rem2queue.remove();
                    if(!rem2queue.isEmpty()) rem2queue.remove();
                }
                resList.addAll(rem1queue);
                resList.addAll(rem2queue);
                resList.addAll(rem0queue);
                resList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

                for(int x: resList) sbResult.append(x);
                //if((Integer.parseInt(sbResult.toString())) % 3 != 0) return result;
                result = Integer.parseInt(sbResult.toString());
                break;

            case 2:
                if(!rem2queue.isEmpty()) rem2queue.remove();
                else {
                    if(!rem1queue.isEmpty()) rem1queue.remove();
                    if(!rem1queue.isEmpty()) rem1queue.remove();
                }
                resList.addAll(rem2queue);
                resList.addAll(rem1queue);
                resList.addAll(rem0queue);
                resList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

                for(int x: resList) sbResult.append(x);
                //if((Integer.parseInt(sbResult.toString())) % 3 != 0) return result;
                result = Integer.parseInt(sbResult.toString());
                break;
        }


        //System.out.println("Sum of digits " + sum + "\n" + "Rem num " + rem + "\n"+ "Result num " + sbResult);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try input array {5} or {5, 5} for instance

Comment: {5} {5,5} throws NumberFormatException :) wtf

Comment: thanks a lot dude :)   "if(resList.isEmpty()) return result;"